# multiline sed substitution overwrites previous output

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am trying to do a sed substitution over two lines like this:

```
sed -r '/user-type/{N;s/user-type: (.*)\n.*gth: .*([0-9]+).*$/\1 \2/}'
```

I got this syntax from an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string), which explains I first match the first line of the pattern and then add the next line to the pattern space with `N` to make the substitution. This has worked for me on previous occasions, but this time the weirdest thing happens.

For input:

```
user-type: admin
password minumim length: 8
user-type: auth
password minumim length: 8
```

I get:

```
 8min
 8th
```

When I expected:

```
admin 8
auth 8
```

It looks like the second saved match is printed from the beggining of the line and replaces what was previously printed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command works for me:

```
$ sed -r '/user-type/{N;s/user-type: (.*)\n.*gth: .*([0-9]+).*$/\1 \2/}' file.txt
admin 8
auth 8
```

If, however, if convert the input to DOS format, I get the output that you see:

```
$ sed -r '/user-type/{N;s/user-type: (.*)\n.*gth: .*([0-9]+).*$/\1 \2/}' <(sed 's/$/\r/' <file.txt)
 8min
 8th
```

One solution is to convert your input file to unix-style line-endings.

Another solution is to adjust the sed command to be tolerant of `\r` characters:

```
$ sed -r '/user-type/{N;s/user-type: (.*)\n.*gth: .*([0-9]+).*$/\1 \2/; s/\r//}' <(sed 's/$/\r/' <file.txt)
admin 8
auth 8
```

Or:

```
$ sed -r '/user-type/{N;s/user-type: ([^\r]*).?\n.*gth: .*([0-9]+).*$/\1 \2/}' <(sed 's/$/\r/' <file.txt)
admin 8
auth 8
```