# Using sed to edit a string over two lines

Tags: sed

I have a file which includes consecutive lines like this

```
macroa{abc def 123 ghi}
macrob{abc 123 xyz}
```

I want to check if the first string in macrob is the same as in macroa and
if it is to delete it so the result is

```
macroa{abc def 123 ghi}
macrob{123 xyz}
```

I'm using the whole file approach from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string/26290) and my command is

```
sed -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -e 's/\(macroa{\([a-z]*\) [^\n]*\)\n\(macrob{\)\2 /\1\n\3/g' in > out
```

However this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong thank you.

Comment: If you're using GNU `sed`, this should work. What result are you actually getting?

Comment: @Kusalananda Nothing gets changed. I'm using GNU sed.

Comment: Try with the examples you posted: It works. Could it be that your code has tabs instead of the spaces as separator after `abc`? This would get converted to spaces when pasting it to your question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your script with GNU `sed` and it produced the expected result. However, this is not portable to other `sed` versions, as you use `\n` inside `[]` and in the replacement, which is undefined by the standard.

Using it in the replacement can easily be avoided:

```
sed -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -e 's/\(macroa{\([a-z]*\) [^\n]*\)\(\nmacrob{\)\2 /\1\3/g'
```

To use it in the `[]` expression can be done with a trick -- you use the `y` command to exchange the newline with a normal character before the replacement and change it back afterwards; in this case I use `|`:

```
sed -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -e 'y/\n|/|\n/;s/\(macroa{\([a-z]*\) [^|]*\)\(|macrob{\)\2 /\1\3/g;y/\n|/|\n/'
```

This is the universal solution, however I think it's ugly. In most cases, instead of `[^\n]`, you can write `[[:print:]]`, because typically all code except for the newlines consists of printable characters, so it's:

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;g;s/\(macroa{\([a-z]*\) [[:print:]]*\)\n\(macrob{\)\2 /\1\n\3/g'
```

(I also simplified your initial `1h;2,$H` to `H;1h`.)

Considering don_crissti's comment, I add that the typical approach to solve this kind of Problem is the `N;P;D` cycle: Always add the `N`ext line, process both together, `P`rint the first line and `D`elete it from the pattern space to continue with the second:

```
sed 'N;s/\(macroa{\)\([a-z]* \)\(.*\nmacrob{\)\2/\1\2\3/;P;D'
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Your versions work fine.

Comment: You are right, @don_crissti, so I added the better approach how you would usually solve this with `sed`. When I help children with math, I usually help them solve the problem their way, before I I show a different (better) approach to solve it. I should not skip the second part.

Answer (score 1):

If are okay with using `awk` instead of `sed`

```
$ awk -F'[{ ]' 'c && c-- && $1=="macrob" && $2==s{sub(s" ", "")}
                $1=="macroa"{c=1; s=$2} 1' ip.txt
macroa{abc def 123 ghi}
macrob{123 xyz}
```

- `-F'[{ ]'` use `{` or space character as field separator
- `$1=="macroa"{c=1; s=$2}` if first field is `macroa`, initialize counter with `1` and save second field in a variable. The counter determines which following lines has to be checked
- `c && c--` this will be true as long as counter is non-zero. Since `c=1` in this case, only once this will be true and irrespective of further conditions, counter will become zero. So, only consecutive lines can match
- `$1=="macrob" && $2==s` required condition

  - `sub(s" ", "")` remove the string and a space character
- Further reading: [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern)