# Using sed to replace multiline

Tags: sed, yaml

I'm trying to replace the following section of a YAML file:

```
  ssl:
    enabled: false
```

to read

```
  ssl:
    enabled: true
```

I've tried this, which failed: `sed -i s/ssl:\n    enabled: false/ssl:\n    enabled: true/g`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `sed` ranges:

```
sed '/^ *ssl:/,/^ *[^:]*:/s/enabled: false/enabled: true/' file
```

The range boundaries are `/^ *ssl:/` (start of the ssl section) and `/^ *[^:]*:/` (any other section).

The `s` is the usual substitution command.

Answer (score 4):

Use a YAML-aware tool. For example, in Perl, you can

```
perl -MYAML=LoadFile,DumpFile -we '
    $y = LoadFile("file");
    $y->{ssl}{enabled} = "true" if $y->{ssl}{enabled} eq "false";
    DumpFile("file.new", $y);'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I will agree with @choroba and tell you to use a tool able to parse and write yaml. Sed parsing is not the right way. you might have different indentation, several continuous endlines. The regexp would get overly complicated and you would end up writing your own Yaml parser.

Here is a solution in ruby
That you can use in Bash shell

```
echo "ssl:
enabled: false
" | bundle exec ruby -e "require 'psych';
 c = Psych.load(STDIN.read); c['ssl']['enabled'] = true;
 puts c.to_yaml" > updated_dest.yml
```

if you want a shell script that takes two params, its also easy

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'psych'
c = Psych.load_file(ARGV.shift)
c['ssl']['enabled'] = true
File.open(ARGV.shift, 'wb+') {|f| f.write(c.to_yaml)}
```