# How to combine strings from JSON values, keeping only part of the string?

Tags: text-processing, sed, json, filter

I have sample:

```
           "name": "The title of website",
           "sync_transaction_version": "1",
           "type": "url",
           "url": "https://url_of_website"
```

I want to get the following output:

```
"The title of website"    url_of_website
```

I need to remove the protocol prefix from the URL, so that only `url_of_website` is left (and no `http` in the front).
Problem is I'm not quite familiar with `sed` reading multiple lines, doing some research reach me https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337399/256195, still can't produce the result.

A valid json object that I'm trying to parse is `Bookmark` of google chrome , sample:

```
{
   "checksum": "9e44bb7b76d8c39c45420dd2158a4521",
   "roots": {
      "bookmark_bar": {
         "children": [ {
            "children": [ {
               "date_added": "13161269379464568",
               "id": "2046",
               "name": "The title is here",
               "sync_transaction_version": "1",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "https://the_url_is_here"
            }, {
               "date_added": "13161324436994183",
               "id": "2047",
               "meta_info": {
                  "last_visited_desktop": "13176472235950821"
               },
               "name": "The title here",
               "sync_transaction_version": "1",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "https://url_here"
            } ]
            } ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a valid json object?  Also jq or json is the proper tool for this, not sed.

Comment: You don't parse JSON with `sed`.  JSON is a structured document format unsuitable for parsing by anything other than a JSON parser.  Doing it with `sed` would require you to implement a JSON parser in `sed` that could handle the different entity encoding etc. that could be present in the data (especially in URLs).

Comment: @Jesse_b: Thanks, I've just added the json object, and if possible jq and json also work if it can solve the issue.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Thanks, I'll edit the title and change content to suit the context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works on the JSON document given in the question:

```
$ jq -r '.roots.bookmark_bar.children[]|.children[]|["\"\(.name)\"",.url]|@tsv' file.json
"The title is here"     https://the_url_is_here
"The title here"        https://url_here
```

This accesses the `.children[]` array of each `.roots.bookmark_bar.children[]` array entry and creates a string that is formatted according to what you showed in the question (with a tab character in-between the two pieces of data).

If the double quotes are not necessary, you could change the cumbersome `["\"\(.name)\"",.url]` to just `[.name,.url]`.

To trim the `https://` off from the URLs, use

```
.url|ltrimstr("https://")
```

instead of just `.url`.

Comment: Thanks, at the end of the file I get this errror: `jq: error (at Bookmarks:23397): Cannot iterate over null (null)`, 23397 is the last line of the file.

Comment: So I've just modified your command, the correct one should be: `jq -r '.roots.bookmark_bar.children[]|.children[]?|["\"\(.name)\"",.url]|@tsv'` that eliminate the above error. One more question, Is that `space` or `tab` between title and url? What if I need to insert tab between them?

Comment: @TuyenPham, it's a tab. "@tsv" is a jq formatter for *tab*-separated values. You could also use `@csv` to get output like `"The title here","https://url_here"`

Comment: @TuyenPham I only had the partial document that you provided to look at, so no wonder there were errors. Good work sorting them out! The `@tsv` command formats the array that it gets as a tab-delimited string.

Comment: How to trim both `http://` and `https://`?

Comment: I see, it's `.url|ltrimstr("https://")|ltrimstr("http://")|ltrimstr("www.")` to trim `http://`, `https://` and `www.`