# jq: parse json file with constraint from other field

Tags: text-processing, json, filter, jq

Extend of this question: [How to combine strings from JSON values, keeping only part of the string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/484933/256195)
Above link's output also include the `"name"` of `folder` type, need to exclude these `"type"`:

```
           "date_added": "13170994909893393",
           "date_modified": "13184204204228233",
           "id": "2098",
           "name": "ElasticSearch",
           "sync_transaction_version": "1",
           "type": "folder"
```

How to get only field if `"type"` of the same object is `"url"`, otherwise ignore:

A valid pattern that will be put in the output:

```
           "type": "url",
           "url": "https://url_here"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an array of objects, `jq` can select the ones that fulfil a certain criteria using `select()`.

It sounds like you may want to use

```
.array[] | select(.type == "url")
```

Given a JSON document like

```
{ "array": [ { "type": "folder", "name": "example folder" },
             { "type": "url",    "name": "example url"    } ] }
```

the above query will return

```
{
  "type": "url",
  "name": "example url"
}
```