# jq: colorize selected field of json file

Tags: text-processing, json, filter, jq

Extend of this question: [jq: parse json file with constraint from other field](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485125/jq-parse-json-file-with-constraint-from-other-field)

After select `"name"` field I'd like to colorize it:

```
{
   "checksum": "9e44bb7b76d8c39c45420dd2158a4521",
   "roots": {
      "bookmark_bar": {
         "children": [ {
            "children": [ {
               "date_added": "13161269379464568",
               "id": "2046",
               "name": "The title is here",
               "sync_transaction_version": "1",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "https://the_url_is_here"
            }, {
```

After google for a while and read through `jq`'s manpage, seem we can set color via variable called `JQ_COLORS` with default `JQ_COLORS=1;30:0;39:0;39:0;39:0;32:1;39:1;39`, I don't have it in my env so I manually set on (I shouldn't because it's default - hardcoded somewhere), and test against `jq` command, but the output has no color (output is just a field, not an json object). I so guess the color through `jq` is for json object, not the selected field.

So I'm asking is there a way to set color for the selected field with `jq`?

EDIT: I'm stuck with `-r` or not `-r` option to `jq`:
With this command:

```
jq -r '.roots.bookmark_bar.children[]|.children[]|["\"\(.name)\"",.url]|@tsv' json_file`
```

I have expected result of:

```
"something here has spaces and inside a double quotes"   solid_line_without_space
```

But If I leave `-r` option, I have command:

```
jq '.roots.bookmark_bar.children[]|.children[]|["\(.name)",.url]|@tsv' json_file`
```

and the result like below - not expected, `\t` can't be expanded:

```
"something here has spaces and inside a double quotes"\tsolid_line_without_space
```

**Question 1**: how to achieve result:

```
"something here has spaces and inside a double quotes"   solid_line_without_space
```

without `-r` option, I really need color on here.

**Question 2**: Because I filter two fields in my query, how to keep color on only field `"name"` and not on field `"url"` - in fact it can be extended to how to customize color of each field (guess I have to modify `JQ_COLORS`)

**Question 3**: extended question: how to keep color of fields if I pipe it through another filter, e.g: `jq <..> | sed <...>`?

**Question 4**: How to have a customized separator? here I had `@tsv` as sym for `<tab>`, what if about a separator like `|` - `space|space`?

Comment: `jq` will colourise JSON output. If you use `jq` with `-r`, you don't get JSON output and hence no colours. What does your command look like?

Comment: Which version of `jq` are you using?  [`JQ_COLORS` is new in 1.6](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.6).

Comment: It's newest `jq`, ver 1.6. If I don't give `-r` option then the output is `"\"A<..>` that add extra `\"`. With `-r` I got what is expected `"A<..>`. So `-r` brings more than just color/not.

Comment: My bad, that's just from `jq` command with `-r` that need to preserve `"` so `\"`, but without `-r`, it's not required.

Comment: So, is your problem solved?  If not, please clarify (by editing the question): what is the complete `jq` command you ran, what is the full output, and which bit(s) of it do you want to appear differently?

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question. @JigglyNaga

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not sure what exactly the problem is. If this is about how `jq` colorizes the output, have a look at `man jq`:

```
   o   --color-output / -C and --monochrome-output / -M:

       By default, jq outputs colored JSON if writing to a terminal. You can force it to produce color  even  if
       writing to a pipe or a file using -C, and disable color with -M.
```

So when writing to a pipe, you are not writing to a terminal, which is why there are no colors. Test it by comparing

```
echo '{"foo":"bar"}' | jq .
echo '{"foo":"bar"}' | jq . | cat
```

And you can turn on coloring again by adding `-C`:

```
echo '{"foo":"bar"}' | jq -C . | cat
```

If you want to do something more difficult, like imitating the way `jq` colors JSON values, but you don't want it for JSON field names, or just for some parts of the object, please update your question.

Note that coloring just consists of adding escape codes to the output. You can imitate this in various ways.

Comment: Thanks, almost solve all my questions. But with `-C`, I got in situation that `\t` can't be expanded: `"something here has spaces and inside a double quotes"\tsolid_line_without_space`

Comment: Also, because two field has same color with default of `jq`, how to inline imitate the second field, like to white color one?

Answer (score 1):

From [the jq documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Colors):

> To configure alternative colors just set the `JQ_COLORS` environment variable to colon-delimited list of partial terminal escape sequences like `"1;31"`, in this order:
>
> - color for null
> - color for false
> - color for true
> - color for numbers
> - color for strings
> - color for arrays
> - color for objects

Those are the only components you can change, and you get exactly one setting per entry in the list.  You can't pick and choose individual members with `JQ_COLORS`, so all strings will be handled the same.

As your output is no longer in JSON, there's no requirement to keep handling it in `jq`.  You could pass it to another command to add the correct terminal escape sequences.  See eg. ["Friendly" terminal color names in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92563/friendly-terminal-color-names-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with using sed to colorize the field instead.