# Replacing multiple lines with sed using a scriptfile (sed -f)

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting, regular-expression

Based on the awesome answer found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string), I'm trying to use some of these commands inside a `sed` scriptfile that will be called using `sed -f`. The file has multiple `sed` commands and it's been working without a problem. Now I need to add these two lines to the end of the file:

```
/^$/{N;s/^$\nbegin of this/begin/g}
/^$/{N;s/^$\nend of this/end/g}
```

which basically searches for an empty line (`^$`) followed by the next with the phrase `begin of this` or `end of this`, and proceeds to delete the empty line and replace the next line just with `begin` or `end`.

Each command run independently works without any problems but when put inside a scriptfile, hell breaks lose. Some of my previous commands stop working (i.e. `s/\\ \\ //g` which just deletes the string `\ \`). More importantly, only the first, of the previous two multiline commands, is executed, why? Am I missing some command-line switch for `sed`? Is it possible to have multiple multiline commands in the same scriptfile?

As extra "points", I would love to replace those two regex lines with a capturing group, i.e. `/^$/{N;s/^$\n(begin|end) of this/\1/g}` but that also doesn't work, not even running it directly on the command line.

I really hope this has a relatively easy/doable solution since I rather not use `perl` or `awk`, but if this is a limitation of `sed` itself or it's extremely complicated to accomplish, I will (very much reluctantly) use the alternatives.

Here's a very basic sample text:

```
some text

begin of this
some more text

end of this

A sentence

Another sentence
```

Which should end up looking like this:

```
some text
begin
some more text
end

A sentence 

Another sentence
```

Comment: Hi. Please paste the entire script you have so far and an example of the input file. That would make the issue so much clearer.

Comment: Let just say for the sake of example that the entire script is just the previous two lines, you'll see that only the first one is executed. I'm running it with `sed -r -f`. I'll add a sample text to the question

Comment: Do you want just the empty lines before those keywords removed or all? Try this first `sed -r '/^$/{$!N;s:^\n(begin|end) of this$:\1:}' file.txt`.

Comment: Only the first of the two commands is executed because the first command changes the pattern space so that it's no longer empty. Each command is applied to the pattern space, as it is at that point in the script. A `/^$/` doesn't "look for" empty lines. If the pattern space is empty at that point in the script, it matches.

Comment: @Kusalanda so I should use the hold space too? How do I do that? Or can I just run a single multi-line command with capturing groups? The capturing groups weren't working either

Answer (score 0):

I think @seshoumara solved it, right? anyways, I came up with this

```
sed  -r '/^$/{N; s/\n(begin|end) of this/\1/g}' file
```