# Replace Tag of and xml file after pattern matching using shell

Tags: shell, xml

I have an input xml file like below

INPUT FILE

```
<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>
<Code>777</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Saurav</entryName>
<Code>666</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Ankur</entryName>
<Code>555</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>
```

I want to comment the tag if i find the pattern "Total Deep" so that the output file looks like below

OUTPUT

```
<!--<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>
<Code>777</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>-->


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Saurav</entryName>
<Code>666</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Ankur</entryName>
<Code>555</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>
```

Since i am new to shell scripting, can anyone help me out as to how i can apply this with the help of shell scripting?

Comment: There are tools for XML processing. To start, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91791/grep-and-sed-equivalent-for-xml-command-line-processing.

Comment: i have to do with shell scripting

Comment: Assuming that <ReconSummary> is not nested, use `awk`. When you detect this tag, collect lines in an array until you reach <entryName>. If it contains *Total Deep*, write "<!--", then the lines from the array. Write the rest until you hit the closing tag, then write "-->". If it contains something else, do the same but omit the comment strings.

Comment: Since i am new to shell scripting can you please help me out with the code for awk?

Comment: It would take me too long to do that for free.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to use an XML parsing tool like `xmlstarlet` to *delete* bits of XML matching some particular XPATH pattern.

In this case, to delete all `ReconSummary` nodes whose `entryName` child node has the value `Total Deep`, you would do

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//ReconSummary[entryName = "Total Deep"]' file.xml >newfile.xml
```

... assuming your file is a well-formed XML file (which your example isn't since it lack as single top-level node).

However, to *comment out* a bit of XML is a bit trickier, and `xmlstarlet` can't do it directly.

You can instead apply an XSL transformation which rewrites your XML.

Using [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/589458/116858) that I wrote to a similar question, the XSL transformation

```xsl
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/|node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//ReconSummary[entryName = 'Total Deep']">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!-- </xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> --&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

would insert the XML comment markers `<!--` and `-->` around every `ReconSummary` node whose `entryName` child node had the value `Total Deep`.

You would apply this XSL transformation to your XML file using either of

```
xmlstarlet tr transform.xsl file.xml >newfile.xml
```

or

```
xsltproc transform.xsl file.xml >newfile.xml
```

where you file is `file.xml` and the transformation is stored in `transform.xsl`.