# Getting syntax error exception for “expr”

Tags: shell, xml, expr

I have an xml file which looks like below

INPUT XML FILE

```
<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>
<Code>777</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Saurav</entryName>
<Code>666</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Ankur</entryName>
<Code>555</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>
```

I was trying to search the pattern "Total Deep" and after that i want to comment out the the tag after 3rd or 4th line of the matching pattern in xml file

My code is below

```
while read -r line do;
LineNum=`grep -n "Total Deep" input.xml | cut -d: -f 1`
TOTAL=`expr $LineNum + 4`
echo $LineNum
echo $TOTAL
done < file.txt
```

While executing the code i am getting below exception

```
expr: syntax error
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

Comment: Could you please check what the output of `grep -n "Deep" Formula.xml | cut -d: -f 1` is?  In general, it would be better to parse the XML file using an XML parser, such as `xmlstarlet` (but I'm a bit confused about what you're wanting XML line numbers for, as the XML format is not line oriented).

Comment: The output is the line numbers where Deep is present like for eg 39806 and 45608 and i need to use it via shell scripting

Comment: So, you get _multiple_ values back?  Do you recognize that using _multiple_ values in `expr` at the same time would be a problem? What you have is something like `expr 39806 45608 + 9`.  It would be better to tell us what the XML file is and what values needs to be extracted from it to achieve what you want to do.  Using `grep` is not the right approach to reading an XML file.

Comment: i have modified my questions and the xml file details has been added in my question. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Which line do you want to comment out?  You say 3rd _or_ 4th. Do you mean the `<job>` tag?

Comment: The 4 line or the 3rd line i want to comment out like the 4th line after the matching pattern is <job>1234</job> or the 3rd line after the matching pattern is <Tran>H20</Tran>

Comment: Sorry, which line do you want to delete? Both the `<job>` and the `<Tran>` lines? I don't understand it when you say "or".

Comment: Like for example i want to comment out the 4th line but not delete  <job>1234</job> so that the output becomes <ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>
<Code>777</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<!--<job>1234</job>-->
</ReconSummary>. This is just an example of the 4th line. The file contains other values in the 4th line as well. So i specifically wnt to comment the f4th line after the matching pattern

Comment: See also: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `grep` returns multiple line matching your expression.  What you end up executing with `expr` is something like `expr 1 3 4 + 4` (if there are matches on lines 1, 3, and 4).  This is where your syntax error comes from.

---

From comments, it is clear that you want to comment out a particular child node from a particular `ReconSummary` node.  If you had wanted to *delete* e.g. the `job` node, I would have suggested using

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//ReconSummary[entryName = "Total Deep"]/job' file.xml >newfile.xml
```

... but commenting out rather than deleting is a bit more tricky.

Similar to [an answer to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638564/116858) that I wrote just moments ago, this would be done with an XSL transformation:

```xsl
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/|node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//ReconSummary[entryName = 'Total Deep']/job">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!-- </xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> --&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

The XPATH query `//ReconSummary[entryName = 'Total Deep']/job` matches the `job` child node of the `ReconSummary` node whose `entryName` child node has the value `Total Deep`.

You can change this easily to instead comment out the `Tran` node.  The XPATH query for that would be

```xsl
//ReconSummary[entryName = 'Total Deep']/Tran`
```

To match both the `job` and the `Tran` node, use

```xsl
//ReconSummary[entryName = 'Total Deep']/*[name()='job' or name()='Tran']
```

As in my previous answer, you would apply this XSL transformation to your XML file using either of

```
xmlstarlet tr transform.xsl file.xml >newfile.xml
```

or

```
xsltproc transform.xsl file.xml >newfile.xml
```

where you file is `file.xml` and the transformation is stored in `transform.xsl`.