# sed giving me this error: … unknown command: `

Tags: shell, sed, xml

I have code which will replace the xml tag at a particular line number

```
 LineNum=`grep -n "Deep" file.xml | cut -d: -f 1 | awk -F '[\t]' '{$NF = $NF -1;}1'`
    sed "${LineNum}s#^<Deep>#<!--<Deep>#" file.xml
```

While executing the command i am getting below exception

```
sed -e  expression  #1, char 7: unknown command `'
```

Can anyone provide me the solution for this?

Comment: Works for me in `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`. No exception, and does the edit (obviously I changed LineNum to 3 for my test). Is it possible there is an invisible character (like '\r') after the `...205` ?

Comment: Might be there is an invisible character. So how can i exclude the invisible character here using the script?

Comment: actually i am taking the line number of a file using LineNum variable with command grep -n command in a while loop. and after then i am using the sed command for replacing the tag in the line number

Comment: Try running the script with `bash -x` and run `LC_ALL=C sed -n l < the-script` to spot invisible characters in it.

Comment: See also: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: Please add clarifications into your question ([Edit](/posts/638602/edit) link under it), not in comments.

Comment: I tried and there are no invisible characters. the problem is why i am still getting sed -e  expression  #1, char 7: unknown command `'. When i am giving the line number without a variable it is working fine. But there are multiple line number where i need to change. So for that i am using while loop to pickup multiple lines and assigning that LineNum varible inside sed command and then exception is happening.

Comment: So, instead of describing, in comments, the code that you're _actually_ running, consider including that code in your question in place of the code that is working, even for you.

Comment: I have modified my code

Comment: You still have the same issue that I commented on in comments and in my answer to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638546/getting-syntax-error-exception-for-expr).  You get _multiple_ line numbers back.  You can't use this as a single number.

Comment: "actually i am taking the line number of a file using LineNum". Yes, that is exactly the problem. Why not echo the sed command that is failing? and then you will understand why it throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that you are using line-oriented tools for editing data that is clearly not oriented in lines but as XML...

To insert the string `<!--` in front of any line that contains the string `Deep`, use `sed` like so:

```
sed '/Deep/ s/^/<!--/' file.xml >newfile.xml
```

There is no need to first calculate the line numbers with `grep` or any other tools, as far as I can see.

Would you want to insert the `<!--` string at the start of the line *above* whatever lines contain `Deep`, then use

```
sed -e '1 { h; d; }' -e '/Deep/ { x; s/^/<!--/; x; }' -e x -e '$ { p; x; }' file.xml >newfile.xml
```

Or, if the file will fit easily in memory, script the `ed` editor (this may actually be the most flexible approach):

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/Deep/-1 s/^/<!--/' 'w newfile.xml' 'q' | ed -s file.xml
```

Comment: This printf '%s\n' 'g/Deep/-1 s/^/<!--/' 'w newfile.xml' 'q' | ed -s file.xml works perfectly if i want to insert the <!-- string at the start of the line above whatever lines contain Deep. However i also need to add --> at the 36 the line after the pattern matching at the end of the tag so the output looks like </ReconSummary>-->. I am using the code printf '%s\n' 'g/Deep/+36 s/$/-->/' 'w newfile.xml' 'q' | ed -s file.xml. But it is not giving the desired output.

Comment: @DEEPMUKHERJEE You question only concerned adding `<!--`. Conisder updating your question if you have other requirements.

Answer (score -2):

does this help?

```
LineNum=$(grep -n "Deep" file.xml | cut -d: -f 1 | awk -F '[\t]' '{$NF = $NF -1;}1')
```

then run the sed line (or maybe also adjust that one):

```
sed $LineNum 's#^<Deep>#<!--<Deep>#g' > file.xml
```

Comment: sed "$LineNums#^<Deep>#<!--<Deep>#" file.xml -> this is not changing anything. The variable name is LineNum

Comment: Note that you use an unset variable called `LineNums` in your `sed `call. Also, it's unclear what you have changed in the code that that the user posted, apart from using `$(...)` in place of a backticked command substitution.  When you correct the unset variable's name, this still has the same issue as the original code in that it will fail if there are multiple matches in the XML document.