# Match the pattern and if the pattern is found then comment the tag based on line number

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, xml

I have the input XML file which looks like below

INPUT XML FILE

```
<Formula>
<Name>Total Hate Fee</Name>
<Code>1234>
<Job>BO</Job>
<Type>sub</Type>
</Formula>


<Formula>
<Name>Total BO Fee</Name>
<Code>1234>
<Job>BO</Job>
<Type>sub</Type>
</Formula>


<Formula>
<Name>Total BO Fee</Name>
<Code>1234>
<Job>BO</Job>
<Type>sub</Type>
</Formula>
```

I want my shell script to search the pattern "Total Hate Fee" and if the pattern is found then i would like to comment that particular line add `<!--` and `-->` just at the pattern match so that my output looks like below

OUTPUT XML FILE

```
<Formula>
<--<Name>Total Hate Fee</Name>-->
<Code>1234>
<Job>BO</Job>
<Type>sub</Type>
</Formula>


<Formula>
<Name>Total BO Fee</Name>
<Code>1234>
<Job>BO</Job>
<Type>sub</Type>
</Formula>


<Formula>
<Name>Total BO Fee</Name>
<Code>1234>
<Job>BO</Job>
<Type>sub</Type>
</Formula>
```

Can anyone help me out on this? Please note I do not want to use `xmlstartet` tool. Instead I want to use shell scripting

Comment: I purged all the comments. If you need to clarify the question, then please [edit] the question.  I'm also confounded by your refusal to use a tool specifically written to work with XML files.  I would also appreciate it if you could keep to a single user account, and not switch between three different ones.  It makes your issue easier to track.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638522/replace-tag-of-and-xml-file-after-pattern-matching-using-shell/638564#638564

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v pattern="$yourMatch" '
    $0 ~ pattern{ $0= "<!--" $0 "-->" }1' infile
```

Note that, at above `pattern`, would match as regex against the `$0` we used; to use `pattern` as string instead, use as following:

```
awk -v string="$yourMatch" '
    { if(index($0, string)) $0= "<!--" $0 "-->" }1' infile
```

Comment: Thanks. Great it worked.

Comment: @PiyushChakraborty If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. I just added the second line of ed code which is looking 4 lines below the matched line.

```
printf '%s\n' \
    'g/Total Hate Fee/-1 s/^/<!--/' \
    'g/Total Hate Fee/+4 s/$/-->/' \
    'w newfile.xml' 'q' \
| ed -s file.xml;
```