# sed - Replace '^M,' when I cant write '^M'

Tags: sed, cygwin

I'm using cygwin to connect to a tiny VM with limited RAM (512M).

Also, I'm trying to import to a sqlite3 db from a 4GB csv file and I don't have any clue on import, except 2 lines (8.717.201 total)

Seems that I have a control-m char (^M) on 2 lines, so it  break csv format and fail to import.

When I try to use `sed 's|,^M|,|' file.csv` control-m char is write textual ASCII (2 chars), so it doesnt search-replace.

When I do it with a test file, opened in `vi` for search and replace, I can see that is write as code (blue colored ^M and act like a single char)

How can I fix the csv file? (or how I can write again the control-m sequence on cygwin?

Example problematic line:

```
$ cat -e test
keyword3,keyword1,keyword4$
keyword1,keyword2,keyword3^M$
,keyword4$
keyword5,keyword1,keyword2$
```

How should be:

```
$ cat -e test
keyword3,keyword1,keyword4$
keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4$
keyword5,keyword1,keyword2$
```

PS: As you can see, english is not my native language, so.. sorry for any mistake ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Related: [What is `^M` and how do I get rid of it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it). In the Cygwin terminal, you should be able to use `Ctrl-V` then `Enter`. At least with GNU sed, you can also use `\r` in place of `^M`

Comment: This recent question [How to remove \n in a string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653224/how-to-remove-n-in-a-string) is also relevant since you are both dealing with line endings that are (legally) embedded within [CT]SV files.

Comment: why comma in `sed 's|,^M|,|' file.csv` ? It should be  `sed 's|^M||' file.csv`

Comment: If the control character is only on two lines, as you say, it might make sense with such a large file to only do substitution on the affected lines, e.g. `sed '1,2 s|^M||'` if they were on first two lines. As for the first sentence of your question, is that related in any way? If that's a separate issue you should create a new question for it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that carriage return helps you identify wrong line breaks:

```
s '/^M$/{N;s/^M\n//;}' test
```

As steeldriver wrote, you can usually produce that `^M` by <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.

The command means

- `/^M$/{...}`: On lines with a page break at the end of a line execute commands in curly brackets
- `N`ext appends the next line to the buffer with the newline between the lines embedded
- `s/^M\n//` `s`ubstitutes the carriage return + newline with nothing (removes the line break)

This simple script assumes that a line is broken maximum one time. Otherwise you'd need something like

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/^M\n//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the method to obtain a `^M` representing a new line (or enter) for replacement on sed or vi is to type :

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: Sorry.. I don't even know why I used french in the first place..